# how to make callback in android + viewModel

Tags: android, concurrency, android-asynctask, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel

Hello I'm trying to use the new architecture components by jetpack.
So how the AsyncTask will be deprecated, how could I do a callback in android to get the result from a background thread. without my app lag

```
 public void btnConfigurarClick(View v) {
    btnConfigurar.setEnabled(false);
     myViewModel.configurar(); // do in background resulting true or false
     // how to get the result of it with a callback to set enable(true)
```

...

Comment: Using `LiveData`.

Comment: You can use an interface or use live data, it's work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of Callback gets converted to Subscribe/Publish in terms of ViewModels.
From Acvitity/Fragment, you would need to subscribe to a [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) that exists inside the ViewModel.
The changes would be notified as you are observing.

Ex :

```
Class SomeActivity : Activity{

    fun startObservingDataChange(){

        yourViewModel.someLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { data ->
            // Whenever data changes in view model, you'll be notified here
            // Update to UI can be done here
        }
    }
}

Class SomeViewModel{

   // Observe to this live data in the View
   val LiveData<String> someLiveData;

   // Update happens to live data in view model

}
```

You can learn more about Architecture Components in [this](https://github.com/android/sunflower) app.